# bootstrap chrome maxOS input on dropdown not typing

Tags: macos, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have got a weird problem on Chrome Mac OS. The text box wont let you type anything into it and when you close the dropdown and then reopen the dropdown the text is there.

www.transportxtra.com click on login box.

does anyone have any theories?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue just in case anyone gets this issue one day, after hours and hours of debugging it was

.dropdown {display:inline;}

issue that was causing a weird input field not to be populated with text when typing.

I hope this helps someone one day.